# Can lease holder physically remove my items from home without judges order?

Tags: canada, british-columbia, real-property

I live in a shared home and pay rent to the lease holder. He doesn't want me to live here anymore. The leaseholder basically said he has the right to kick me out whenever he wants and to remove my belongings. Is this right? Can he take my belongings and put them on the street?

I'm guessing not - for example even if someone is staying in your home as an unpaying guest, it wouldn't give you the right to pickup their jacket and throw it outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't have a lease and my landlord is threatening to kick me out immediately](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/39280/i-dont-have-a-lease-and-my-landlord-is-threatening-to-kick-me-out-immediately)

Comment: @DavidSiegel FYI: That question is on the close queue. closing this as duplicate will make the duplicate target hard to delete.

Comment: It's also the same user asking both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, no. But it would depend on a number of factors such as the nature of the agreement to rent (written contract, sub let, if you are on the lease or not, if the landlord knows about you etc), and the nature of the eviction (reasonable notice, reason for doing so, term of agreed lease etc). If you could provide more detail with those issues I may be able to assist.

Comment: An official lease was not signed but I exchanged an email with the lease holder that specified the rent, damage deposit etc. He replied agreeing to this email. It was never discussed how the arrangement could be ended. The reason he is evicting me is because he's renting out the house to more people than there are rooms. I complained and this is how he reacted. The whole question is, how much time must he give me? He has said if I don't agree to additional "rules" he would immediately evict me.

Comment: So is the leaseholder just a tenant or is he the owner of the property

Comment: Was the tenancy agreement for a fixed term? And are you part of a sublet?

Comment: He is just a tenant. It was not fixed term.

Comment: BTW thanks a lot for your help. It means lot.

Comment: Ok so unfortunately if its an agreement with a tenant or roommate, the Tenancy Act doesn't apply. However, you may find some value in contacting the actual landlord to sort this out as if the tenant is acting in dubious circumstances he may back down at risk of losing his own lease agreement. I'd recommend finding the realestate agency who manages the lease and getting in contact with the landlord about signing onto the lease as soon as possible. The only way you can be protected under the law is if everything is above board.

Comment: I'd say something along the lines of; I've been paying rent to your property but your current tenant is trying to evict me illegally under an illegal sublease, so in order to protect your interests as a landlord and my interests as a tenant, it would be mutually beneficial to have a signed lease agreement for a fixed term under the tenancy laws.

Comment: The Tenancy Act does not apply but the rest of laws apply. Wouldn't taking my belongings count as theft?

Comment: Yes it would. But it becomes dubious as to wether he has right to kick out out of the premises considering the nature of the agreement. i.e. Can a tenant remove someone if they are seen as trespassing etc.  I'd advise to avoid the fight and go to the land lord directly, get on the lease and have the protection of the law.